# Varnish and custom blocks

Tags: 8

I want to configure varnish on my drupal 8 multilingual website and I have a block that appears on a page whose  path is /my-test . So in french the url would be like this : /fr/my-test whereas in english /my-test . In this block, I simply use:

`$lang = \Drupal::languageManager()->getCurrentLanguage()->getId();` to detect the language and then  display news depending on this language.
so when the url is /my-test > the language is english (default)> the block displays news  related to the world.
when the url is /fr/my-test > the language is french > the block displays news  related to the France.

My question is, if varnish is used and pages like /my-test is cached. If at first place, a user enters /my-test and the block displays news about the world then after that, another user visits /my-test/fr . Will the block display news about the world (because the page is cached) despite having /fr in the url? or will it display the right content (news related to France)?
I suppose that `$lang` detects the language from the url prefix not from the user's browser.

Comment: Varnish is typically configured to cache by URL. Different URL, different cache entry.

Comment: You want to look at Cache Contexts (https://www.drupal.org/docs/drupal-apis/cache-api/cache-contexts). I believe Drupal pushes these out to Varnish in the page headers, so that Varnish will vary the cache accordingly.

Comment: @Jaypan So  I assume that the block will display the right content event though in the link you sent  LanguageInterface is mentioned instead of languageManager ..

Comment: @Clive I am also using `$active_id = \Drupal::service('domain.negotiator')->getActiveId();` in this same block code and I had the same doubt regarding this expression, so thanks to your answer I know that $active_id won't be the same for both users since the URL is different :)

Comment: @Clive comment is correct. Varnish can't cache `/my-test` if you have browser detection enabled. So you need to add a path prefix for the default language, too, and then redirect to that. On the redirected page you can use varnish.

Comment: I assume you've posted this question unregistered https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/307459/varnish-in-multilingual-site.

Comment: Thank you so much @4k4 . what do you mean by "if you have browser detection enabled" ? How can I enable that ? I still cannot figure out what  a  language detection method  is.  I don't think I have browser detection enabled. because when you enter  my website,  you are asked to choose a language and then we redirect you to this language prefix.

Comment: /admin/config/regional/language/detection

Comment: @4k4 I have these enabled : Country Path Language Handler URL, URL (path prefix), selected language. Browser is disabled. so i assume it's good